# How to include a PHP variable inside MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, variables

I wanna add an extra column to my database and give it the name `price_23-05-2019`.

How do I put this into a working query?

I have this right now, which is clearly not working:

```
  $date = date("d-m-Y");

  $query = 
  "ALTER TABLE `products_05_2019`
  ADD price_'.$date.' DECIMAL(7,2)";

($result = mysqli_query($link, $query))
```

Comment: Question is valid but really makes me question your database design. In 20 years I've never had a schema where I added columns from code. Does the MySQL user have permission to alter the table? Ideally your applications connection would not have those rights.

Comment: What @ficuscr says, don't do it.  That should be data.

Comment: I agree with @ficuscr, there are probably much better ways to do what you are trying to do. This screams "bad database design" to me.

Comment: It's for setting up my database real quick, because I'm not gonna put 365 days in there manually. I figured with php I could make a loop, but first I need to figure this out. Plus I'm not looking for this advice, can't you just tell me how to do it haha

Comment: @Jerooney You shouldn't need a column for every date; that's the problem.

Comment: Google something like "10 common database mistakes"... Trying to find a good resource to share... FWIW: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/58036/how-to-handle-table-design-with-variable-columns

Comment: @Jerooney It's better to have more rows than more columns. For example, say you have a table `products` which contains all the info about topics, except for the prices (That's what it looks like you are trying to do). This `products` table has a primary key, make another table `prices` with the columns `product_key`, `price`, `date`.  Now for each date, add a new row to the `prices` table that is linked to the primary key from `products`, this way you can query the database and pull all the prices for a specific product.

Comment: @Jerooney If you create a table with 4 columns it would be easier to create and manage. The table would have the following columns id (primary_key), product, price and date.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Thank you, I'll try it that way.

Answer (score 2):

You really shouldn't have separate columns for each date. There should just be a `date` column, with the date as the value, and a separate row for each date.

But if you have to do it this way, here's how to solve it.

If you use `-` in a column name, you have to enclose the name in backticks.

```
  $date = date("d-m-Y");

  $query = 
  "ALTER TABLE `products_05_2019`
  ADD `price_$date` DECIMAL(7,2)";

  $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
```

But it would probably be better to use `_` instead of `-`.

```
  $date = date("d_m_Y");

  $query = 
  "ALTER TABLE `products_05_2019`
  ADD price_'.$date.' DECIMAL(7,2)";

  $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
```

Comment: Now at least I'm clear on why it probably didn't work for OP.

Answer (score 0):

As @ficuscr says above, you may want to have a look at the design of your database so you don't have to create columns from code.

Anyway, what I use to do when I have a column name depending on code is create a new variable and then include it into the query:

```
  $date = date("d-m-Y");

  $column_name = 'price_'.$date;
  $query = "ALTER TABLE `products_05_2019` ADD `$column_name` DECIMAL(7,2)";
```

Comment: While I applaud you for finding an answer to the question, I believe this whole question should be [frame challenged](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6842/whats-a-frame-challenge/6843#6843) so OP can learn why this is not a good idea and to explain the correct way to handle the situation.

Comment: I have a large database with products. I want to keep track of the prices of every day. So I wanna run this code every day, download the updated database with new prices, add a column with the price of that day and put the data in there. How else would you suggest to do that?

Comment: @Jerooney Check my comment on the question

Comment: @Jerooney Create a table with 4 columns: id, product, price and date